# Does IOS 12.4 Basic have the “ip nat pool …” available

Tags: cisco, ip, nat, ios, pool

Could someone with Cisco IOS 12.4 Basic check to see if the command "ip nat pool" is available?

We have 12.2 basic and I know it is in the 12.4 advanced version but our budget is very limited so I am hoping that 12.4 basic has this command.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Cisco's [feature navigator](http://cisco.com/go/fn) [here](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/by-feature.jsp), it looks like NAT is supported even on IP-only and IP BASE images.